# How to open/convert old jbuilder java GUI files in netbeans

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, netbeans, jbuilder

If have a problem concering an old java project done with jbuilder. I converted it into a netbeans project and it works fine. However i can´t open the GUI files originally written in the jbuilder ide. So i do not have the possibility to adapt/open these files by the netbeans forms editor. 
Sure i can edit the plain code, but thats quite annoying because of the complexity. Also i can´t see any .forms files from the jbuilder project which i expected. 
So, my question is, is there a way to open dialog GUI files created by jbuilder in a netbeans swing forms designer for adaption? 
Is there a conversion tool, or something?

thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Downloading the JBuilder Project Importer Module**

> You can download the JBuilder Project Importer Module to import
>   projects that you have developed with JBuilder 2005 into NetBeans IDE.
>   (For NetBeans IDE 5.5, this module can also import projects developed
>   with JBuilder 2006). This module eliminates or greatly reduces the
>   amount of work you have to do get your projects working in NetBeans
>   IDE as they worked in JBuilder.

**To download the JBuilder Project Importer module:**
Start NetBeans IDE.

- In NetBeans IDE, choose Tools | Update Center.
- In the Update Center wizard, select the JBuilder Project Importer module and complete the wizard.

#### Importing the JBuilder Java SE Project Into NetBeans IDE

Once you have the importer module added, you can import Java SE projects from JBuilder with a simple wizard.

#### To import a general Java project into NetBeans IDE:

- In NetBeans IDE, choose File | Import Project | JBuilder Java Project.
- In the wizard, specify the JBuilder project file (Project to Import field) and the folder where you want the NetBeans IDE project metadata to be created (Destination Folder field).
- In the NetBeans IDE 5.5 version of the project importer, you also are presented with JBuilder User Home and JBuilder Installation Folder. Filling in these fields (where appropriate) makes it easier for the IDE to handle any dependencies that the project has on other projects or libraries.
- The IDE leaves the project sources where they are so that you can still work with them in JBuilder.

#### Building and Running Your Application

- To build your application, right-click the project's node in in the Projects window and choose Build Project.
- To run your application in the IDE, right-click the project's node in in the Projects window and choose Run Project.

Note: When you build and run applications in NetBeans IDE, the output also includes output from the Ant script that the project is based on. If you are not specifically concerned with the working of the Ant script, you can ignore that part of the output.

[For more information on importing projects into NetBeans IDE 5.0](https://netbeans.org/kb/archive/index.html)

Comment: thx for your fast reply. unfortunately i´m using netbeans8.0 so i can´t find any jbuilder project importer module for it?! There is no tools | update center so i tried tools| plugins but no luck. Has anyone an idea to get this work with netbeans 8.0?

Comment: check the link hope you find an answer @user3887028